# Customize Select's Source Image Admin Template

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I run this model in Admin Template, is displayed an  component and an image with a link to add new *User*. I would like to know how to change the image's source of link. The default value is

```
/static/admin/img/admin/icon_addlink.gif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the template for the add Client form.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options is what you're looking for, although I will say overriding django admin templates can become messy when you upgrade to a later version of django.